# Liferay : Any one has updated jquery.tweet.js?

Tags: jquery-plugins, liferay-6, liferay-velocity, liferay-theme

Has any one used and updated jquery.tweet.js for liferay 6.1

after following important note from seaofclouds.com,

```
Important note about Twitter's API changes
Twitter has discontinued its unauthenticated v1.0 API, 
so this widget has stopped working as of 2013-06-11.

Twitter wants your only option for on-page widgets to be 
their own Embedded Timelines, but there are workarounds 
which involve installing server-side code to support this widget. 
Please see this discussion for more details.
```

If yes, let me know steps to do ?
I am also trying, If done i ll update

Till then waiting for reply, might be save my time.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Basic wrapper for Seaofclouds / Tweet.js that incorporates functionality with Twitter's v1.1 API

https://github.com/StanScates/Tweet.js-Mod